# Binding Ajax Search Result To TextField

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

The search functionality that I have implemented using Ajax works as expected, the problem that I am facing is I couldn't find a solution to bind the search result to the text field when I click an item from the search result.

The Ajax search results are displayed using resultBox and the input text field used for searching is SearchInput. Upon clicking an item in the resultBox the value needs to be binded to the searchInput. But currently when I click the item in the resultBox the page is getting refreshed.

[image]

```
console.log("Sanity check!");
const url = window.location.href
window.onload = function() {
const searchForm = document.getElementById("search-form")
const searchInput = document.getElementById("search-box")
const resultBox = document.getElementById("results-box")
const csrf = document.getElementsByName("csrfmiddlewaretoken")[0].value

const sendSearchData = (stock_name) =>{

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '',
        data:{
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : csrf,
            'stock_name':stock_name
        },
        success: (res) =>{
            console.log(res.data)
            const data = res.data
            if (Array.isArray(data))
            {  
                resultBox.innerHTML= ""
                data.forEach(stock_name =>{
                    resultBox.innerHTML += `
                    <a href="" style="text-decoration : none;">
                       <div>
                       <p> ${stock_name.symbol_name} </p>
                       <small> ${stock_name.symbol}</small>
                       </div>
                    </a>
                    `
                })
            }
            else
            {
                if (searchInput.value.length > 0)
                {
                    resultBox.innerHTML =`<b>${data}</b>`
                }
                else
                {
                    resultBox.classList.add('not-visible')
                }
            }

        },
        error: (err) =>{
            console.log(err)
        }
    })

}

searchInput.addEventListener('keyup',e=>
{
    console.log(e.target.value)

    if (resultBox.classList.contains('not-visible')){
    resultBox.classList.remove('not-visible')}

    sendSearchData(e.target.value)
})

}
```

Please advise on the correct approach

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you need to add onclick function on anchor tag

```
    console.log("Sanity check!");
    const url = window.location.href
    window.onload = function() {
    const searchForm = document.getElementById("search-form")
    const searchInput = document.getElementById("search-box")
    const resultBox = document.getElementById("results-box")
    const csrf = document.getElementsByName("csrfmiddlewaretoken")[0].value
    
    const sendSearchData = (stock_name) =>{
    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '',
            data:{
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : csrf,
                'stock_name':stock_name
            },
            success: (res) =>{
                console.log(res.data)
                const data = res.data
                if (Array.isArray(data))
                {  
                    resultBox.innerHTML= ""
                    data.forEach(stock_name =>{
                        resultBox.innerHTML += `
                        <a href="" style="text-decoration : none;" onclick="AddToTextBox(this)">
                           <div>
                           <p> ${stock_name.symbol_name} </p>
                           <small> ${stock_name.symbol}</small>
                           </div>
                        </a>
                        `
                    })
                }
                else
                {
                    if (searchInput.value.length > 0)
                    {
                        resultBox.innerHTML =`<b>${data}</b>`
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resultBox.classList.add('not-visible')
                    }
                }
    
            },
            error: (err) =>{
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    
    }
    function AddToTextBox(obj)
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(null!==obj)
     {
       var text = $(obj).text();
       $("#search-box").val(text); 
     }
    }
    searchInput.addEventListener('keyup',e=>
    {
        console.log(e.target.value)
    
        if (resultBox.classList.contains('not-visible')){
        resultBox.classList.remove('not-visible')}
    
        sendSearchData(e.target.value)
    })
    
    }
```